# How to parse this? Trying to pull data from non-HTML webpage using BeautifulSoup and Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

BeautifulSoup & HTML novice here, and I've never seen this type of page before. I'm trying to pull data from the 2008 presidential race in Dane County, Wisconsin.

Link: https://www.countyofdane.com/clerk/elect2008d.html

The data for the presidential race is in what appears to be a hard coded table? It isn't stored in between HTML tags, or anything I've come across before.

Can I pull the data by iterating through the `< !-- #-->` thing somehow? Should I save the page as an HTML file and add in a body tag around the table so its easier to parse?

Comment: You are parsing text at this point. BeautifulSoup won't be of any help. Parsing the actual data will be reasonably straightforward, but the diagonal headings will be... challenging.

Comment: Once you have the text between the `<pre>` and `</pre>` tags you are probably better of parsing with regular expressions.

Comment: @kindall technically parsing the header isn't so complicated. First you have to measure how many lines they occupy. Then you can measure how much space to the right each line has to be prepended. Then each letter starting the column is a name and each letter at the end of the column is an other name. Columns are markes with `----`. Well no it's complicated, just not impossible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem actually comes to *text parsing* since the tables are in *plain text* inside a `pre` element.

Here is what you can start with. The idea is to detect a beginning and an end of a table by using the `-----` headers and empty lines after the tables. Something along these lines:

```
import re

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from ppprint import pprint

url = "https://www.countyofdane.com/clerk/elect2008d.html"
response = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser")

is_table_row = False

tables = []
for line in soup.pre.get_text().splitlines():
    # beginning of the table
    if not is_table_row and "-----" in line:
        is_table_row = True
        table = []
        continue

    # end of the table
    if is_table_row and not line.strip():
        is_table_row = False
        tables.append(table)
        continue

    if is_table_row:
        table.append(re.split("\s{2,}", line))  # splitting by 2 or more spaces

pprint(tables)
```

This would print a list of lists - a sublist with data rows for every table:

```
[
    [
        ['0001 T ALBION WDS 1-2', '753', '315', '2', '4', '1', '0', '5', '2', '0', '1'],
        ['0002 T BERRY WDS 1-2', '478', '276', '0', '0', '0', '0', '2', '0', '0', '1'],
        ...
        ['', 'CANDIDATE TOTALS', '205984', '73065', '435', '983', '103', '20', '1491', '316', '31', '511'],
        ['', 'CANDIDATE PERCENT', '72.80', '25.82', '.15', '.34', '.03', '.52', '.11', '.01', '.18']],
    [
        ['0001 T ALBION WDS 1-2', '726', '323', '0'],
        ['0002 T BERRY WDS 1-2', '457', '290', '1'],
        ['0003 T BLACK EARTH', '180', '107', '0'],
        ...
    ],
    ...
]
```

This, of course, does not include the table names and diagonal headers which can be challenging to get, but not impossible. Plus, you would probably want to separate total rows from the other data rows of a table. In any case, I think this can be a good starting example for you.

Comment: Sorry, two noob questions:  1) What does ".pre" do in "for line in soup.pre.get_text().splitlines():"   2) I'm struggling to further ppprint, can you point me towards the documentation? Want to make sure I'm looking at the same thing as you

Comment: @kfish15 sure, no problem. 1) the `soup.pre` is equivalent to `soup.find("pre")`. 2) `pprint()` is just for pretty-printing, there is no functional  purpose for using it in the code sample. Thanks.